# rails heroku asset precompile fail due to rake version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

When I tried to push to heroku I get this msg:

`rake aborted!
       undefined method empty? for nil:NilClass
       (in /tmp/build_3d16ad44-0015-4ecb-a7cf-a41959f03f82/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)`

Upon tracing it, I realized that it's because

`rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 10.0.3, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2.2. Using bundle exec may solve this.`

This may be a really dumb question, but I am not sure how I am supposed to use bundle exec to do this for heroku?  Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: How are you precompiling the assets? I think Heroku is precompiling them (while you are pushing to Heroku)? What version of Rails?

Comment: heroku was precompiling them upon pushing.  I am using rails 3.2

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else runs into a similar issue.  The problem was that heroku was using ruby 2.0 with all their new apps so in order to do that you have to put whatever ruby version you are using on the gemfile then reset git by typing `git reset --soft HEAD~` and then `git reset HEAD public/assets` into your command line.  And `rm -r public/assets` if you have untracked files in public/assets.  Then save the changes and push up to your new site.

So if your app uses an older version of ruby than 2.0, you will have to make similar changes until the bug (sprocket?) is fixed.

Comment: noob i am also have this same issue.. i don't know how to trace my problem, plzzz give procedure to trace my problem....

Answer (score 0):

Inside the project directory in terminal:

```
gem list rake
```

You will see more than one version. If so, then remove the version you don't need (i.e. 10.0.3 in your case) by command:

```
gem uninstall rake
```

It will ask you specific version to select from list, choose one and press enter.

**Or, you can also update to specific rake version**

```
bundle update rake -v '0.9.2.2'
```